# Orchard New List Feature Missing

Tags: .net, list, orchardcms

I'm trying to create a new list of a custom content type following [this overview on OrchardProject.net](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-lists).  However, I do not have the New > List option, and do not see it in my list of installed modules, and can't find it on the site.  How can I get the list feature enabled?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been deprecated. Use Projector or taxonomies instead. The module is still available on the gallery, but it's not recommended.

Comment: Is using Contents and Containers modules to create custom containters still recommended?

Comment: If that's really the scenario: items being contained in one container each, like files in folders. But in most cases Taxonomies or Projector will be a better fit. What's your scenario?